# Issue with text not showing due to Overflow Hidden

Tags: html, css

So bit of background on my issue. I'm using an external [carousel](https://github.com/matiascodesal/spCarousel) and I am trying to modify each image section to include text. There seems to be an `overflow:hidden` on the *sp-carousel-frame* class that is making it not visible but without this the unselected images on either side go full size.
I basically need the *item-text* class to be displayed.

I really hope I explained this ok.

I'm going include an image that shows the issue below.

[image: Text]

HTML

```
<script src="https://wordpress-84115-1849710.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/themes/inspiration-marketing-theme/assets/js/carousel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container collaboration-header">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Collaboration and Teamwork</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container main-carousel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="sp-carousel-frame sp-carousel-frame-pos">
                <div class="sp-carousel-inner">
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item" style="overflow: visible !important;">
                        <img src="https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Main-Slider-Image.jpg"/>

                        <div class="item-text">
                           Hello World
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item"><img src="https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Left-Slider-Image.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item"><img src="https://gdxdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Right-Slider-Image.jpg"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.collaboration-header h1{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5em 0;
}

.main-carousel {
    margin-bottom: 20% !important;
}
```

The JSFiddle Below:

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garathd/0b9618ar/7/)

Comment: you what to display "hello word" in bottom, yes?

Comment: Yes, Sorry if it wasn't explained well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it solved basically although I probably need to tweak it a bit to get it perfect what I did was disable the `overflow:hidden` on the *sp-carousel-frame* and change it to visible. Then on the parent div *col-md-12* I attached another class called overflow:

HTML

```
        <div class="col-md-12 overflow">

            <div class="sp-carousel-frame sp-carousel-frame-pos">

                <div class="sp-carousel-inner">
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item" style="overflow: visible !important;">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Main-Slider-Image.jpg"/>

                        <div class="item-text">
                           Hello Hows it going like
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Left-Slider-Image.jpg"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sp-carousel-item"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Right-Slider-Image.jpg"/>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- End sp-carousel-frame -->
            <hr />
        </div><!-- Close Col-md-12 -->
```

CSS:

```
.sp-carousel-frame {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.overflow {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/garathd/0b9618ar/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Add Class this `carousel-caption` on `item-text`

```
<div class="item-text carousel-caption">
    Hello World
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/3hyb82fg/1/

Comment: Sorry this is not what I want. I want the text underneath the images and not over the image. Thanks